# Connecting to a MIDI Input port and simulating input (Python)

Tags: python, midi

I've got an electronic piano that lacks the pitch bend and modulation wheels. I'm looking for a way to simulate them while still giving output through the same MIDI port the device is connected. The rest I'll figure out myself.

I'm using Windows and Python 3.5. Thank you for your time.

Comment: There are several libraries available for python3, like pygame.midi or mido,  that you can use to send MIDI events to a connected MIDI device. Which one you want to use, and what is the problem exactly?

Comment: I want to connect to a MIDI input port that my piano is connected to and "add" virtual/fake MIDI input (whatever the channel that the modulation wheel to is), so other programs like, Kontakt, for example, will recognize it all in one port.

Comment: That is not possible, in Windows. You can do that on macOS or Linux, but in Windows a program can only connect (read/write) to a driver (of a hardware device), not another program. To solve this problem you can install virtual MIDI cables, like [loopMIDI](http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/loopmidi.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look forward to try loopMIDI as well as any other possible workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **loopMIDI** worked for me. What it does is simply puts its Output as its Input, so when sending modulation wheel (or other) events to Output (I had to use `output.write_short(0xb0, 1, modulation)`, Pygame) it will send those events directly to Input and then it'll be possible to use it as a MIDI input device in workstations and etc.